# Traffic camera datasets

Tags: transportation, images

I'm searching dataset with photos of front cars, like speed camera photos.
Standford dataset is interesting, but too good quality, not from traffic cameras.

Who knows where to find such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Data Ottawa's data portal has this data:
[Traffic Web Cam Images Dataset](http://data.ottawa.ca/dataset/traffic-web-cam-images)
"Provides images for the City of Ottawa's traffic web cams. These images are available at sixty second intervals. To access the images users will be required to have an access key."

### More Options, and Resources:

#### Image Datasets

[Application form for access keys](http://trafficopendata.ottawa.ca/ts/rsadmin/certificate.jsp)
[Caltech Has Two Car Datasets and One Motorcycles Dataset](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/archive.html)
[MIT CBCL Card Database #1](http://cbcl.mit.edu/software-datasets/CarData.html)
[UIUC Image Database for Car Detection](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/Car/)

#### These have some promising leads:

[Computer Vision Datasets](http://clickdamage.com/sourcecode/cv_datasets.php)
[CVonline: Image Databases](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if these cameras are quite right for your purpose, but the Massachusetts DOT has their traffic cameras available via API: https://data.mass.gov/d/spgs-rk4q

Portland Oregon also has their cameras online in some form (can't remember my CivicApps login at the moment, so I'm not sure how good this dataset is): http://civicapps.org/datasets/its-cameras-intelligent-transportation-system