# Traffic camera video datasets

Tags: data-request, traffic, video

Before you refer me to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/traffic-camera-datasets), I must specify that I am looking for *Video* datasets, not still images. All links on that question refer to still images. Most cities/government websites provide one frame per minute or so. Are there sources with at least 15 FPS videos out there?

It doesn't have to be live video, in fact it would be easier for me if it came as a single-file dataset with one JPG file per frame or one video file per feed.

The [UA-DETRAC challenge dataset](https://detrac-db.rit.albany.edu/) is one good example, but it is rather limited in size (it has 40 video sequences), and I'm looking for more data. Are there other good sources?

EDIT: to be clear, by traffic camera I mean a camera that is on a high point and that looks at the passing traffic. The cameras cannot be inside of cars, otherwise I would use KITTI and other similar datasets.

Comment: try contacting these people http://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/~xgwang/MITtraffic.html

Comment: Have you found something similar ?

Comment: @NikolajApostolovski afraid I didn't. UA-DETRAC remains the best dataset. To be fair, you can find a lot of traffic camera *feeds*, they just won't have labels. See e.g. : https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9829/traffic-camera-datasets?noredirect=1&lq=1